# RecyclerView not responding on data change

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview

i have this problem.

I've defined simple activity with `RecyclerView` and i wan't to add an item on button click. I've defined custom `RecyclerView.Adapter` just like many examples available on the internet, but the view doesn't respond to the data change (todos are being added to `todos` list). Could someone please take a look and tell me what am i missing?

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val addButton: FloatingActionButton by lazy { add_button }
    private val todoView: RecyclerView by lazy { todo_view }
    private val todos = mutableListOf<Todo>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        todoView.adapter = TodoRecyclerAdapter(todos)
        todoView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        addButton.setOnClickListener {
            todos.add(Todo("test", "dasdasdas", "11-12-19"))
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean = when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.menu_settings -> true
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

TodoRecyclerAdapter.kt

```
class TodoRecyclerAdapter(private val todos: List<Todo>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder =
        LayoutInflater
            .from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_todo_item, parent, false)
            .let { TodoViewHolder(it) }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
        todos[position].run {
            viewHolder.title.text = title
            viewHolder.dueDate.text = dueDate
        }

        viewHolder.parent.setOnClickListener {
            println("Clicked $position item")
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = todos.size

    inner class TodoViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val parent: ConstraintLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todo_item)
        val title: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todo_title)
        val dueDate: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todo_due_date)
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_margin="8dp" android:id="@+id/todo_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="657dp" android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/add_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

layout_todo_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                             android:background="@color/todoColor"
                                             android:id="@+id/todo_item">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="370dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp" android:id="@+id/todo_title"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/todo_due_date" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:textSize="18sp" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.52"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" android:text="@tools:sample/cities"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="369dp"
            android:layout_height="21dp" android:id="@+id/todo_due_date"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/date/ddmmyy"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Todo is just a simple data class. When i run the app on debug, the TodoRecyclerAdapter methods are not being called at all.

Comment: Adapters do not automatically react to data changes. You have to _notify_ adapters every time there is any change in the data. A single line solution for your example is to put `todoView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()` after `todos.add(...)` inside the click listener.

Comment: It works now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your MainActivity you have the following code:

```
addButton.setOnClickListener {
        todos.add(Todo("test", "dasdasdas", "11-12-19"))
}
```

This simply adds a `Todo` to the list of `todos`. The adapter has already received the list before this change and created the `todoView` accordingly. In order to update `todoView` with the updated list, you need to explicitly tell the adapter that the data has changed.

You can do so like this:

```
addButton.setOnClickListener {
        todos.add(Todo("test", "dasdasdas", "11-12-19"))
        todoView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

However, since you're only adding an item to the list, you may want to use
[notifyItemInserted(int position)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyiteminserted) instead.

Comment: Yeah @Sanlok Lee already commented on that, but thanks anyway.